# Multithreaded Python tcp server with local forwarding

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to come up with a solution for a python tcp socket server. It needs to handle multiple connections, but here's the catch I'm stuck on. When the client connects I can see the remote port assigned and can communicate via other clients connected. I want to be able to connect with a client and send data to specific socket/ Client. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is I have a client behind a firewall. I connect to the socket server on an internet based server. Now I would like to connect to the same server with a different client and send all data through server based on destination port. I know I can do this with ssh2 tunnelling with forwarding, but I'm trying to come up with a way natively in python. Important to note the clients are not python based. Could be anything. For example, vnc on computer. connection to server. Remote vnc viewer connects to server and forwards to already connected socket. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a sample I have so far.

```
import socket, select

sock_config = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock_config.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
sock_config.listen(5)
config = []    

rlist = [sock_config]
wlist = []
errlist = []

out_buffer = []

while True:
r, w, err = select.select(rlist, wlist, errlist)
for sock in r:
    if sock == sock_config:
        conf, addr = sock.accept()
        config.append(conf)
        rlist.append(conf)
    else:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if data.find('[CONNECT]') != -1:            
            sock_clients = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock_clients.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
            sock_clients.listen(2)
            sock.send("12345")
            sock.close()
            rlist.remove(sock)
        else:
            out_buffer.append(data)

    out_string = ''.join(out_buffer)
    out_buffer = []

#for sock in w:
#   print 'Test'

for sock in err:
    sock.close()
    rlist.remove(sock)
```

Can't figure out how to listen to random ports and still be able to read and write to them. There will be multiple clients on random ports.

Comment: Anyone else have any suggestions? I'm stuck on creating and reading from array of sockets that listen on random ports.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `select` function.  It [does what you want](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html), but does so without multithreading.  Instead, it lets you wait for "any socket," and then react to it.  There are many [tutorials](https://pymotw.com/2/select/) on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I did start looking at Select. I guess where I'm confused is with the forwarding part. For example if I have a client connect to server via telnet and it connects on remote port 64233, I want to be able to connect from another client and send and receive data  with only client one.Or if I have vnc server running on client 1, be able to connect to server via vnc viewer and send data to the socket of client 1

Comment: @ABarnes It sounds like it may be worth your time to look into some tutorials on how sockets work.  What you describe is what will happen naturally if you use sockets the way people use sockets.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it well enough. I certainly am aware of how sockets work and function. I'm new to python. The issue is if my client is already connected on a socket (always connected) and lets say the remote port is 64233, how can I connect to server and tell it to send the data to client connected on 64233 and not other clients connected. Quick example is I have a server setup, 3 clients connected. each has vnc server running on them. I connect to server with vnc viewer and want to control Client 2. I will need to fwd data to socket that client 2 is connected on.

Comment: @ABarnes Usually you have a port mapping (in a file).  For example, there  might be a line that says any data that comes in on port 1234 is forwarded to 192.168.1.2:2345.  Then whenever someone connects to the server on port 1234, it opens a new socket to port 2345 on 192.168.1.2 and begins forwarding.

Comment: Thanks but here is the issue with that. Server is external running python server script, listening on port 1234. Client 1 connects from remote LAN to server port 1234. Server shows Client 1 is connected on port 64233. Now I would like Client 2 to be able to connect to server port 64233 and send data directly to Client 1. I have a method to get connected port, but can't figure out how to have server listen on a different port for each connection. Keep in mind this could have many connections

Comment: @ABarnes Ahh, that's an unusual one, because you want the port numbers to match.  I believe you can still do it.  Sockets are actually 4 numbers:  client IP, client port, server IP, server port.  As long as one of those numbers is different, they are deemed to be different sockets.  Thus, once the connection occurs from client1:64233 to server:1234, you can have the server listen on server:64233, accept the connection from client2:XX (where XX is the randomly chosen port on client 2).  Now you have two sockets, client1:64233-server:1234 and server:64233-client2:XX.

Comment: Most servers only `listen` to one port, but in your case, you'd listen to one port initially (1234), and listen to a second port (64233) while waiting for client2 to connect.  Then you'd probably stop listening on 64233 once client1 disconnects.

Comment: Exactly. That's where I'm stuck. So essentially I'm looking for a way for clients to connect and send data to a specific client. The problem is let's say there are 100 clients. Now I'm listening on port 1234 for connections, then I have to listen on another 100 random ports for communication between them. So if I have a client with vnc, it connects a socket to external server. This gets it around firewall issues. Now I would like to connect to that vnc instance from home. So I would connect to server on port that feeds client 1 direct. Make sense?

Comment: The usual approach is to do the connections in one direction.  If your external client connects to the server, that causes the server to create a connection to your local computer.  So let's define three machines, client, server, and vnc (where vnc is your local machine that runs VNC).  VNC is open on vnc:5900, which is a traditional VNC port.  The client then connects to server:1234, which the server and client have previously agreed is the correct way to connect to the vnc machine.  then the server opens up a connection to vnc:5900 and starts routing.

Comment: I think a key to the usual approach is that the client and server have already agreed upon which server port will be forwarded to any given internal port.  As a real life example, I used to have an internal server at 10.0.0.42, which had ssh (port 22) and http(port 80) open.  I set up my forwarding machine to forward all traffic from port 4222 on the outside to 10.0.0.42:22 and all traffic from port 4280 to 10.0.0.42:80.  For the ports I needed to forward, that encoding was sufficient.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I'm trying to get around firewalls. So if VNC is behind firewall, server won't be able to connect unless I have port fwd enabled in router. I'm looking at communication without any change. For example, I can get the results I want by vnc opening ssh tunnel and having a remote port fwd. Then open tunnel from ext client with local forward. info passes between client and vnc with server as middle man. Both outbound connections so no firewall issues. Problem with ssh is tunnel disconnects often and speed is an issue. So trying to find a way to tunnel natively.

Comment: Think of TeamViewer as an example. Server connects to them outbound. Client connects to server with ID and server then routes all client data to and from server

Comment: Do you have a *firewall*, or a NAT that is having the effect of a firewall.  There are known techniques to "punch through" a NAT.  Also, as a consideration, you could always have an extra "configuration" port which you use to send commands like "when I get a connection from X, patch it through to Y"

Comment: To that end, you could have one side connect to this configuration port (let's say port 2000, just to give it numbers).  It connects to server:2000 and sends a command like `CONNECT`.  The server picks a random port (say 45987) and replies with `45987` on the configuration port.  It then starts listening for exactly 2 connections on port `45987`, and begins forwarding between the two sockets that connect.  Then all you need to do is let both parties know that they need to connect to server:45987

Comment: That sounds exactly what I'm looking for. Like I said python is new to me. Any chance you could include a quick example of how?

Comment: Please see my newly posted example in the initial question